# How to create a VB program that auto-fills credentials on other program

Tags: vb.net, authentication, autocomplete

I wish to create a VB program which can auto fill in the credentials (Username and password) on another program.
This is the program I wish to fill the credentials in:

[image]

How do I do it?

I wanted to try SendKeys.
It seems that I need to use my mouse to click the field in order to fill it in.

I hope someone can help me.
Ps: Im using VB 2010

Answer (score 0):

Following your `SendKeys` approach, just try to simulate a **Tabulation** key to navigate through the controls to focus on the desired edit-control then send the desired text simulating the rest of keys.

Example:

```
    For count As Integer = 0 To X ' x = Many times as required to focus the username textbox.
        SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
    Next count

    SendKeys.Send("username")
    SendKeys.Send("{TAB}")
    SendKeys.Send("password")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I tried using tab functions, nothing happen, it doesn't automatically switch fields through "tab"